# selection in dropdown a choice has no effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello here is the HTML code

```
<select name="shoeSize" id="shoeSize" autocomplete="off" class="ncss-ncss-select-menu fs-block css-1bxej0k erx5h8s0" aria-required="false" aria-describedby="shoeSize-select-aria-description">


    <option hidden="" data-testid="hidden-option" disabled="" value="" aria-hidden="true">Pointure</option>
<option value="4">EU 36</option>
<option value="4.5">EU 36.5</option>
<option value="5">EU 37</option>
<option value="5.5">EU 38</option>
<option value="6">EU 38.5</option>
<option value="6.5">EU 39</option>
<option value="7">EU 40</option>
<option value="7.5">EU 40.5</option>
<option value="8">EU 41</option>
<option value="8.5">EU 42</option>
<option value="9">EU 42.5</option>
<option value="9.5">EU 43</option>
<option value="10">EU 44</option>
<option value="10.5">EU 44.5</option>
<option value="11">EU 45</option><option value="11.5">EU 45.5</option><option value="12">EU 46</option>
<option value="12.5">EU 47</option>
<option value="13">EU 47.5</option>
<option value="13.5">EU 48</option>
<option value="14">EU 48.5</option>
<option value="14.5">EU 49</option>
<option value="15">EU 49.5</option>
<option value="16">EU 50.5</option>
<option value="17">EU 51.5</option><option value="18">EU 52.5</option></select>
```

the following commands i put in JS webconsole have no effect on the page....why?

```
document.getElementById('shoeSize').getElementsByTagName('option')[11].selected = 'selected'
```

it is still the same choice, the js code does not change the choice

Comment: Although you should rather use `document.getElementById('shoeSize').value = "9"` your code works fine for me.

Comment: it is weird because on screen the value stays the same

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What does it say when you put just `document.getElementById('shoeSize')` in the console? Or just `document.getElementById('shoeSize').getElementsByTagName('option')[11]`? Anyway, what's the actual issue? Users of your website aren't going to put random commands in the console. Also, when I say "works for me", I mean this: https://jsfiddle.net/wkc2tsnh/

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById('shoeSize').options[11].selected=true`?